# how to ignore empty cells when sorting a tableview/tablecolumn in JavaFX

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I currently have a table with items that can be sorted according to various columns. My current table has empty rows that allow for the insertion of new items on the fly without having to use any external controls (out of table buttons).

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the tableview]

I have not been able to find a solution that would allow me to sort a given column while ignoring empty cells (ie. empty cells should always remain at the bottom of the table while all others are sorted according to need)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom comparator for the column:

```
column.setComparator(...)
```

See here for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602105/1715829